# I want to create a ComboBox which allows the selection of multiple items.

Tags: wpf

How can I create a ComboBox which allows the selection multiple items and adds selections separated with commas in WPF?

Comment: Good luck with your task

Comment: I think you won't get much feedback if you post your question like this.  If you want to actually get some advice on your doubt, you should post what you have tried and/or which difficulties you are facing.  This is what many other users of this site will also tell you to do because your question, as it is now, does not provide any details on what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer as briefly as you asked your question... you could define your own [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) for your `ComboBox` with a `ListBox` in the `Popup` for the items.